# What kind of patterns in a list of rules would benefit from being Dispatched?

Tags: performance-tuning, replacement

I have a long list of rules for manipulating expressions.  They are of the form:

```
complexRules = {f[x_, y_]^2 :> (*something*),
                f[x_, y_] f[x_, z_] :> (*something*),
                f[x_, y_] f[w_, z_] :> (*something*),
                g[x_, y_, z_]^2 :> (*something*),
                g[x_, y_, z_] g[a_, b_, z_]  :> (*something*),
                (*and so on*)}
```

As you can see, the LHS of the rules are fairly complicated patterns.  I don't fully understand the construction and uses of such dispatch tables. But my hunch is that they wouldn't benefit from being `Dispatch`ed as compared to "static" (patternless) rules like

```
simpleRules = {anna :> (*something*),
               bebe :> (*something*),
               cecy :> (*something*),
               deedee :> (*something*),
               eli :> (*something*),
               (*and so on*)}
```

Is my hunch correct in that `complexRules` would benefit less from `Dispatch` than would `simpleRules`?  And if so, by how much?

Comment: Since you are actually using long lists of patterns, you are in a good position to benchmark this!

Comment: What @Szabolcs is trying to say is that the mob demands a benchmark :)

Comment: What did you end up finding for this? The benchmark would be useful to have out there for a number of tests.

Answer (score 8):

Dispatch generates a dispatch table which uses hash codes to specify which sets of rules need actually be scanned for a particular input expression reducing to a minimum lookup time.  Lists of rules produced by assignments made with   = and := are automatically optimized with dispatch tables when appropriate.

[image: Example]

Excerpt From: Mangano, Sal. “Mathematica Cookbook.” O'Reilly Media, 2010-04-02. iBooks. 
This material may be protected by copyright.
Check out this book on the iBooks Store: https://itun.es/us/ApcQx.l

[image: Example]

Excerpt From: Mangano, Sal. “Mathematica Cookbook.” O'Reilly Media, 2010-04-02. iBooks. 
This material may be protected by copyright.
Check out this book on the iBooks Store: https://itun.es/us/ApcQx.l

Below is the performance benefit of using a Dispatch:

[image: Ratio]

99.8 % decrease in CPU time used by the Wolfram Kernel.

[image: CR]

I tried on two different systems and the performance ratio is very similar  to the one shown in the book:

[image: complexRepeatedEvaluation]

Comment: That is some good information about how Dispatch works. Thanks!  Would you know if Dispatch boosts performance for a list of complicated rules (which have quite intricate patterns) just as much as for simple ones (like in the book)?

Comment: @QuantumDot I think you should add this to the body of the question because it is the key point. One one addition: simple rules with patterns are not the same as rules with `Condition` or `PatternTest`!

Comment: I believe it does improve performance. You are right that doesn't include the difficulties of testing and conditions. I think yours is an interesting question. It could be useful if you include a working example to work with or what is happening on your machine. I ask myself these types of questions before as well and it always helps to bring a working example.

Comment: @QuantumDot Why can't you test it on *your* set of rules?